# LINQ's Query using fetch Dictionary object with Room Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dictionary

I have Dictionary like below.

`static Dictionary<string, Room> allRooms = new Dictionary<string, Room>();`

```
public class Room
{
    public String RoomID { get; set; }
    public String TeamID { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<Member> ConnectedUsers { get; set; }
}
public class Member
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionStatus { get; set; }
    public bool MuteChat { get; set; }
}

Member m = new Member { ConnectionId = "2", MemberId = "1", TeamId = "3", UserName = "username", ConnectionStatus = "available", MuteChat = false };
List<Member> connectedUsers = new List<Member>();
            connectedUsers.Add(m);
            allRooms.Add(RoomID, new Room { RoomID = "12", TeamID = "3", RoomName = "roomName", ConnectedUsers = connectedUsers });
```

In the above Dictionary "Room" contains "Members" and "Room" information.
Member contains details of the member like "MemberID" and other fields
So, I know the "MemberID" for particular person. I am using the  below code get then get all members in all rooms. But My requirement is get the memberRooms only. Can you please suggest

```
var connectionid1 = allRooms
                          .Select(i => i.Value).Cast<Room>()
                          .Where(d => d.ConnectedUsers.Count > 0)
                          .Select(d => d.ConnectedUsers).Cast<List<Member>>()
                          .SelectMany(d1 =>
                              d1
                               .Where(d => d.MemberId == userid )).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the **exact** output you expect to see for your above sample data?

Comment: I don´t understand your question. If you want the members only for a specific room, why not use `myRoom.ConnectedUsers`? Anyway get rid of all those `Cast`-calls, your dictionary allready *is* od the right type, no need to cast the `Value` or `ConnectedUsers` to the right type again.

Comment: try using First() or FirstOrDefault() instead of TolList()

Comment: @mjwills, Hi, In the above code, I need output list object with RoomID with member Data is required. But my last query returns in the Member list object only. So how retrieve the RoomID and member info as well?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your member class and add Room's reference to it.

```
public class Member
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionStatus { get; set; }
    public bool MuteChat { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
}
```

To get all the members of a room, use the following code:

```
var MemberList = DB.Members.Where(x => x.RoomID == "RoomID here").ToList();
```

Comment: I don't which room it is.
I know MemberID in the dictionary. If i place the RoomID in the Member object. it is working. here userid i knows, I update the script like this

`var connectionid1 = allRooms
                          .Select(i => i.Value).Cast<Room>()
                          .Where(d => d.ConnectedUsers.Count > 0)
                          .Select(d => d.ConnectedUsers).Cast<List<Member>>()
                          .SelectMany(d1 =>
                              d1
                               .Where(d => d.MemberId == userid )).ToList(); `